# How do I specify dependancies from a custom repository for Linux Deb archives

Tags: install4j

I'm using install4j V 5.0.9 and I make a Linux Deb media file. How can I specify a repository for other dependencies that aren't in the default repository of ubuntu ?

The objectif is to add java for dependencies, not openjdk but sun-jdk. The sun jdk is in an other repository (deb http://archive.canonical.com/ lucid partner).

Answer (score 0):

RPM and DEB media files in install4j do not support dependencies at this time.